# Check version of Xamarin.Android programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

From [Xamarin documentation on Environment Checks](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/projects/environment_checks/), for iOS, I can check the version of Xamarin by accessing `MonoTouch.Constants.Version`.

Is there an equivalent for Xamarin.Android? I want to do this for logging purposes.

Comment: Chris, I've redone my answer to show how we've accessed the version of Xamarin.Android. This was a problem my team had to solve a few months ago and I think it should answer your initial question now.

Answer (score 2):

We've accomplished this through the use of a `*.tt` file to read the Xamarin.Android version file and generate a C# class containing the version information:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 

namespace Versioning
{
    public class XamarinAndroid
    {
    <#

    #if __MonoCS__
        var path = @"/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current";
    #else
        var path = (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)"))
                ? @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android"
                : @"C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android";
    #endif
        string versionText = "unknown";
        if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
            versionText = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(path, "Version"))[0];
    #>
        public const string Version = "<#=versionText#>";
    }
}
```

On the files properties, set the `Custom Tool` property to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`. This will execute the t4 template pre-compilation and generate a static class that contains the Xamarin.Android version that the app was built on.